# Weak star convergence with a dense subset S in V

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Show that $f_{n} \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}f$ in $V^{*}$ if, and only if,

(i) $\{||f_n||\}$ is bounded and,

(ii) $f_{n}(x) \to f(x)$ for all $X\in S$, where $S$ is a
subset of V whose span is dense in $V$.

Some ideas?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: You posted a bunch of questions in the previous hour that are just homework assignments without showing any work on your side.

Comment: I Will upload some anwers next.  I'm preparing for an important test. Unfortunately this Is not a Homework assigment, this Is just practicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\implies$) Take $S=X$ and use the Uniform Boundedness principle to show that $\{\|f_n\|\}$ is bounded.

$\impliedby$) If $\|f_n\|\leq c$ for all $n$, for any $x\in \operatorname{span}S$ you have $x=\sum_{j=1}^m x_js_j$ for scalars $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ and $s_1,\ldots,s_m\in S$. Then
$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^mx_jf_n(s_j)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}
\sum_{j=1}^mx_jf(s_j)=f(x).
$$
When $x\in\overline{\operatorname{span}}S$, let $\{x^{(n)}\}\subset \overline{\operatorname{span}}S$ with $x^{(n)}\to x$. Then
$$
|f_m(x)-f(x)|
\leq |f_m(x)-f_m(x^{(n)})|+|f(x^{(n)})-f(x)|
\leq (c+\|f\|)\,\|x-x^{(n)}\|.
$$